# Overcompleteness of coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, integration, coherent-states

I am trying to show that the basis of coherent states,
$$ |\phi\rangle =e^{-\sum_{\alpha'}\phi_{\alpha'}a^\dagger_{\alpha'}}|0\rangle, \quad\text{ where }\quad a_\alpha|\phi\rangle=\phi_\alpha|\phi\rangle\tag{1},$$
is overcomplete in the Fock space using Schur's lemma. Here, $a_\alpha$ is the annihilation operator for the state $|\alpha\rangle$. The overcompleteness property is given by:

$$ \int \prod_{\alpha}\frac{d\phi_\alpha^*\,d\phi_\alpha}{2i\pi}e^{-\sum_{\alpha}\phi^*_\alpha\phi_\alpha}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|=1 \tag{2}.$$

Schur's lemma states that if an operator commutes with all creation and annihilation operators, then that operator is proportional to the identity. Using the following properties of coherent states:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_\alpha^*}\langle\phi|=\langle\phi|a \implies [a_\alpha,|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|]=\left(\phi_\alpha-\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^*_\alpha}\right)|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\tag{3},$$
where the left-hand side follows from taking the Hermitian conjugate of Eq. (1), we obtain:

$$ \int \prod_{\alpha'}\frac{d\phi_{\alpha'}^*\,d\phi_{\alpha'}}{2i\pi}e^{-\sum_{\alpha'}\phi^*_{\alpha'}\phi_{\alpha'}}[a,|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|]=\int \prod_{\alpha'}\frac{d\phi_{\alpha'}^*\,d\phi_{\alpha'}}{2i\pi}e^{-\sum_{\alpha'}\phi^*_{\alpha'}\phi_{\alpha'}}\left(\phi_{\alpha'}-\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^*_{\alpha}}\right)|\phi\rangle\langle\phi| \tag{4}.$$

Now, some references (e.g. [Negele & Orland](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9780429497926/quantum-many-particle-systems-john-negele-henri-orland)) say this can be done by integration by parts. Using this for the second term above, we obtain:

$$ \int \prod_{\alpha'}\frac{d\phi_{\alpha'}^*\,d\phi_{\alpha'}}{2i\pi}e^{-\sum_{\alpha'}\phi^*_{\alpha'}\phi_{\alpha'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^*_\alpha}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi| = \int \prod_{\alpha'}\frac{d\phi_{\alpha'}^*\,d\phi_{\alpha'}}{2i\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^*_\alpha}\left(e^{-\sum_{\alpha'}\phi^*_{\alpha'}\phi_{\alpha'}}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\right)- \\\int \prod_{\alpha'}\frac{d\phi_{\alpha'}^*\,d\phi_{\alpha'}}{2i\pi}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^*_\alpha}e^{-\sum_{\alpha'}\phi^*_{\alpha'}\phi_{\alpha'}}$$

The second term of the equation above eliminates the first term in Eq. (4), and we are left with

$$ \int \prod_{\alpha'}\frac{d\phi_{\alpha'}^*\,d\phi_{\alpha'}}{2i\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^*_\alpha}\left( e^{-\sum_{\alpha'}\phi^*_{\alpha'}\phi_{\alpha'}}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\right)\tag{6}$$

However, I an unsure about how to evaluate this integral. What is the correct approach to this integral?

Comment: Isn't the integral now just a boundary term?